# Origin of induced emf

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

What is the origin of induced emf in a conductor which is produced by changing magnetic flux.I mean why changing magnetic flux causes the production of induced emf.
Is there some kind of energy involved?Is it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Have a read through the Wikipedia article I've lionked and maybe highlight what aspects of the process you don't understand.

Comment: The deepest answer is probably *relativistic covariance*:  $\Box A^{\sigma} = \mu_{0} \, J^{\sigma}$